# Reversing siblings html elements with Emacs

Tags: emacs

I've a long *list* of divs that I need to reorder (reverse).

I need to transform this (numbered titles were added only for the sake of clarity):

```
<div class="some-classes">
    <h2>Title 3</h2>
    <!-- other html contents but not divs -->
</div>
<div class="some-classes">
    <h2>Title 2</h2>
    <!-- other html contents but not divs -->
</div>
<div class="some-classes">
    <h2>Title 1</h2>
    <!-- other html contents but not divs -->
</div>
```

Into this:

```
<div class="some-classes">
    <h2>Title 1</h2>
    <!-- other html contents but not divs -->
</div>
<div class="some-classes">
    <h2>Title 2</h2>
    <!-- other html contents but not divs -->
</div>
<div class="some-classes">
    <h2>Title 3</h2>
    <!-- other html contents but not divs -->
</div>
```

Is it possible to do this with Emacs?

Comment: I don't know of a M-xxx command to do it, but it's certainly doable in Emacs lisp.  If you don't have to do it often, though, then the easiest thing is probably to split the screen horizontally, position the top pane at the top of the list, bottom pane at the bottom of the list, and then just record a macro (select & yank the bottom, then paste at the top of the top screen.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is certainly more than one way to achieve this in Emacs. For instance, you could do the following. **CAVEAT**: *you've got make sure that you make no mistakes, i.e, no typos when following the instructions below, or else you might not get the results you're after*.

1. Mark the region of your document that contains the `div`'s and then type <kbd>M-x narrow-to-region</kbd>

This will make the following edits somewhat easier and also makes sure that you do not accidentally change parts of the documents you do not want to change.

2. Move to the beginning of the line of the *last* of the `<div class=...>`-entries. Make sure that no region is marked.
3. Type <kbd>C-x (</kbd>

As a result, you should see the message `Defining kbd macro...` in your minibuffer.

4. Hit <kbd>C-space</kbd> to start marking a region
5. Type <kbd>C-r</kbd> to start a backward search.

You should now see `I-search backward:` in your minibuffer

6. Type the string `<div`, and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

While you type in that string, `point` should already move to the beginning of the line of the *previous* `div`, the one just above the last one. The the whole body of that second-to-last `div` should become highlighted as you are marking the region that contains it. (This automatic marking of the region is why we did step 4. above.)

7. <kbd>C-w</kbd> will kill that region, i.e., will delete the complete second-to-last `div`-section from your buffer.
8. Type <kbd>M-></kbd> to jump to the end of the buffer
9. Type <kbd>C-y</kbd> to insert the `div` you just deleted at the end of your buffer
10. Type <kbd>C-u C-space</kbd> and then again: <kbd>C-u C-space</kbd>

The `point` should now be back at the beginning of the `div` that was the last `div` in the buffer when we started.

11. Type <kbd>C-x )</kbd>

The last step should give you a message `Keyboard marco defined` in the minibuffer. Now comes the magic:

12. Type <kbd>C-x e</kbd>

Emacs will automatically repeat steps 4-10 for you with the effect of moving another `div` section to the end of the buffer.

13. Keep typing the character <kbd>e</kbd> until the whole list is reversed.

Finally, get the rest of the contents of your file back for editing:

14. <kbd>M-x widen</kbd>

Comment: It works nicely, thank you. The only difference in my setup is the "jump to the end of buffer" command, that is bound to `M->`.

Comment: No, you're right, that was a mistake on my side. Thanks for pointing it out, I fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

*A. Manually (slow if you have many such elements to sort):*

1. `M-x nxml-mode RET`
2. `M-x set-variable nxml-sexp-element-flag t RET`
3. `M-<` `C-M-t` `C-M-t` `C-M-t` `C-M-b` `C-M-b` `C-M-b` `C-M-t` `C-M-t`

   or

   `M-<` `C-M-f` `C-M-t` `C-M-t` `C-M-b` `C-M-b` `C-M-t`

   or

   `M-<` `C-M-f` `C-2` `C-M-t` `C-2` `C-M-b` `C-M-t`

   or

   `M-<` `C-M-k` `C-M-f` `C-M-t` `RET` `C-y`

   or

   `M->` `C-M-<backspace>` `C-M-b` `C-M-b` `C-M-t` `C-M-b` `C-M-b` `C-y`

   or

   `M-<` `C-M-f` `C-M-k` `C-M-t` `C-M-b` `C-y` `RET`

   or

   `M-<` `C-M-f` `C-M-t` `C-M-k` `C-M-b` `C-M-b` `C-y` `RET`

   etc.

   Step 2 lets the sexp commands treat a full element as a sexp (otherwise, it treats only a tag, such as `<div class="some-classes">` or `</div>`, as a sexp).

   `C-M-f` and `C-M-b` move over sexps (elements, in this case).

   **`C-M-t`** *transposes the elements before and after point.*

   `C-M-k` kills the next element. `C-M-<backspace>` kills the previous element.

*B. A command to do it all: `M-x foo`:*

```
(defun foo ()
  "Reverse the order of the top-level elements in buffer."
  (interactive)
  (let ((nxml-sexp-element-flag  t)
        (o-mode                  major-mode))
    (unwind-protect
         (progn
           (goto-char (point-min))
           (nxml-mode)
           (sort-subr
            nil
            (lambda () 
              (forward-sexp) 
              (unless (eobp) (backward-sexp)))
            (lambda () (backward-sexp) (forward-sexp))
            nil
            'forward-sexp
            nil))
      (funcall o-mode))))
```

See the Elisp manual, node [Sorting](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sorting.html).